# Angular Material md select option group default selected values

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How do i set specific items in my list to be selected values in md-select option group.

For example, when i load the page i want to see Alice and Steve to be checked already. i tried to set the model by putting values but it does not work.

```
$scope.users = [
       { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
       { id: 2, name: 'Alice' },
       { id: 3, name: 'Steve' } ];

$scope.selectedUser = [{ id: 2, name: 'Alice' },{id: 3,name:'Steve'}];

<md-input-container>
   <label>Users</label>
     <md-select ng-model="selectedUser" multiple="">
        <md-optgroup label="Users">
        <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users">{$ user.name $}</md-option>
        </md-optgroup>
      </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ng-selected.
Unfortunately it seems that ng-selected doesn't take a function. So you have to use a ternary operator.

```
<md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-selected="user.name === 'Bob' ? true : (user.name === 'Alice' ? true : false)">{{ user.name }}</md-option>
```

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/7JP324sDwJOQCITriptq?p=preview)

Comment: `ng-selected="user.name == 'Bob' || user.name == 'Alice'"` also works.

Comment: Glad I could help. But also have a look at C14L's answer. I wasn't aware of the trackBy funktionality with ng-model and I find it's a cleaner seperation of concerns

Answer (score 4):

Using [ng-model-options](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) (see last example in the page). So your md-select you look like this:

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedUser" multiple="" 
           ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/phfr901dzmnjpEz77Ja3?p=preview)